# extract more string json to php

Tags: php, json, string

I have json data here.

```
{"data":{"bid":[{"cid":"1244343","crid":"1090868","creativeId":0,"lastUpdateTime":1587667678,"credits":1,"ext":{"type":"VIDEO","class":0,"xButtonBehavior":"buttonHidden","templateid":"0","notificationsData":{"duringData":"","afterData":"","nextData":"Next"},"counterData":{"completionCountdown":30,"timeUntilTimer":0,"showTimer":false,"percentage":false},"videoData":{"autoPlay":true,"videoType":"ssa-internal-video-player","videoTime":30,"videoSource":{"videoformat_mp4":"https://cdn.com/files/videos.mp4","html":""},"videoPoster":""},"enableLogo":true,"removeNext":true,"appData":{"appIcon":"https://platform.com/banners/images.png","title":"FarmVille 2: Country Escape","description":"app","appImages":["https://cdn.com/image/a.jpg"],"adAssets":{"both":["https://cdn.com/image/a.jpg"]},"appId":"com.escape","appSize":120,"numOfReviews":2765261},"clickTags":{"index":1,"clickURL":"**https://playog.com**","title":"DOWNLOAD NOW","pixURL":"https://hapons.com"},"callbacks":{"imp":[{"at":0,"url":"**https://comenicad.com**","percentage":false,"type":"pix"}],"29":[{"at":29,"url":"**https://pixtra.com**","percentage":false,"type":"pix","event":"notify"}]},"features":{"wiggle":true,"allowHybrid":false,"isVideoClickable":true,"externalBrowser":false,"ccvaf":false,"allowNativeEndCard":false},"forceOrientation":"Landscape","opportunityID":"opp_101","orderID":47053}}],"ext":{"requestID":"2f6158b1-8996-11ea-bb55-41b78e2aaca7","auction":{},"randomSeed":850307660,"numOfBannersToCache":1,"numOfBannersToInitSuccess":1,"landingId":10356,"strategyId":197,"refreshInterval":30,"DEC":3,"purgeCacheOnInit":false,"allowMultiInitCalls":false,"openLandingPageInExtBrowser":false,"pagination":false,"labels":{"confirmCloseMsg":{"during":{"close":"No rewards earned yet! Complete video to earn rewards","yes":"Stop","no":"Resume"},"after":{"close":"Want to earn more free Virtual Item?","yes":"No Thanks","no":"Earn More"}},"next":"Next","noInternet":"No internet connection. Please connect and try again.","noOffers":"There are currently no videos available. Please try again later."},"filterAppsInstalled":true,"immersive":true,"vastAvailabilityValidation":true,"reportOnAdunitReady":false,"deviceType":"phone"}}}
```

how do i retrieve data from json to php output.
php code.

```
<?php
$json = '{"data":{"bid":[{"cid":"1244343","crid":"1090868","creativeId":0,"lastUpdateTime":1587667678,"credits":1,"ext":{"type":"VIDEO","class":0,"xButtonBehavior":"buttonHidden","templateid":"0","notificationsData":{"duringData":"","afterData":"","nextData":"Next"},"counterData":{"completionCountdown":30,"timeUntilTimer":0,"showTimer":false,"percentage":false},"videoData":{"autoPlay":true,"videoType":"ssa-internal-video-player","videoTime":30,"videoSource":{"videoformat_mp4":"https://cdn.com/files/videos.mp4","html":""},"videoPoster":""},"enableLogo":true,"removeNext":true,"appData":{"appIcon":"https://platform.com/banners/images.png","title":"FarmVille 2: Country Escape","description":"app","appImages":["https://cdn.com/image/a.jpg"],"adAssets":{"both":["https://cdn.com/image/a.jpg"]},"appId":"com.escape","appSize":120,"numOfReviews":2765261},"clickTags":{"index":1,"clickURL":"https://playog.com","title":"DOWNLOAD NOW","pixURL":"https://hapons.com"},"callbacks":{"imp":[{"at":0,"url":"https://comenicad.com","percentage":false,"type":"pix"}],"29":[{"at":29,"url":"https://pixtra.com","percentage":false,"type":"pix","event":"notify"}]},"features":{"wiggle":true,"allowHybrid":false,"isVideoClickable":true,"externalBrowser":false,"ccvaf":false,"allowNativeEndCard":false},"forceOrientation":"Landscape","opportunityID":"opp_101","orderID":47053}}],"ext":{"requestID":"2f6158b1-8996-11ea-bb55-41b78e2aaca7","auction":{},"randomSeed":850307660,"numOfBannersToCache":1,"numOfBannersToInitSuccess":1,"landingId":10356,"strategyId":197,"refreshInterval":30,"DEC":3,"purgeCacheOnInit":false,"allowMultiInitCalls":false,"openLandingPageInExtBrowser":false,"pagination":false,"labels":{"confirmCloseMsg":{"during":{"close":"No rewards earned yet! Complete video to earn rewards","yes":"Stop","no":"Resume"},"after":{"close":"Want to earn more free Virtual Item?","yes":"No Thanks","no":"Earn More"}},"next":"Next","noInternet":"No internet connection. Please connect and try again.","noOffers":"There are currently no videos available. Please try again later."},"filterAppsInstalled":true,"immersive":true,"vastAvailabilityValidation":true,"reportOnAdunitReady":false,"deviceType":"phone"}}}';
$jsondata=json_decode($data);

print_r($jsondata->{'clickTags'}[0]->{'clickURL'}); //output blank/not working
echo "<br />"; 

print_r($jsondata->{'imp'}[0]->{'url'}); //output blank/not working
echo "<br />";

print_r($jsondata->{'29'}[0]->{'url'}); //output blank/not working
echo "<br />";
```

get someone help me write the correct php code?

Comment: You need to `print_r($jsondata);` to see the structure.  `$jsondata->data->bid[0]->ext-> clickTags->clickURL`  etc, etc...

Comment: And it doesn't output blank.  Turn on error reporting _Notice: Undefined variable: data
Notice: Trying to get property 'clickTags' of non-object
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null
Notice: Trying to get property 'clickURL' of non-object<br />
Notice: Trying to get property 'imp' of non-object_

Comment: _Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null
Notice: Trying to get property 'url' of non-object<br />
Notice: Trying to get property '29' of non-object
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null
Notice: Trying to get property 'url' of non-object<br />_

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
print_r($jsondata->data->bid[0]->ext->clickTags->clickURL); 
echo "<br />"; 

print_r($jsondata->data->bid[0]->ext->callbacks->imp[0]->url); 
echo "<br />";

print_r($jsondata->data->bid[0]->ext->callbacks->{29}[0]->url); 
echo "<br />";
```

I hope it helps you